# Unsafe column names

Tags: mysql, sql

I have always used backticks (`) to execute my SQL queries. However, recently, I learned that if I excluded them, column names such as "From" will be interpreted differently.

Now, for safety reasons, I'd just like to know exactly which other words I shouldn't use as column names, in case I would ever make a query without backticks (or worse - it's not supported in a later MySQL version).

Correct me if I've gotten this wrong, but function names (such as "Password") are safe to use, right?

Comment: See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

Answer (score 4):

See the list of MySQL reserved words: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

Answer (score 1):

A detailed list of reserved keywords can be found at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html